# How to make query with three different parameters

Tags: wordpress

I have three different parameters to search with, first one is post title of custom post type, second is taxonomy term and third is post type also, I am able to search if three of them are selected, but how to search related records if two of them are selected only or just one of them ?

```
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'course',
            'post_status' => 'publish',

            'tax_query' => array(

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'course-category',
                    'terms' => $cs_course_cate,
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    )               
            ),

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'cs_course_campus_id',
                    'value' => $cs_campus,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            ),
        );
```

[View Search Box Here](http://prntscr.com/ihrrh8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    if(!empty($cs_course_cate)){
        $args = array('tax_query' => array(

            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'course-category',
                'terms' => $cs_course_cate,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                )               
        ));     
    }


    if(!empty($cs_campus)){
        $args = array('meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'cs_course_campus_id',
                'value' => $cs_campus,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),            
            )
        );      
    }
```